# Isolated storage best way to store data in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

i am storing data to windows phone isolated storage using below code but performance is slow because its chat application so i need to store the message continuously.what is the best way to achieve this .sometimes its throw memory issue.

My code for storing data

```
 using (MYDataContext objDB = new MYDataContext(DBConnectionString))                    
 {                       
  myTable newrecord = new myTable 
     {
       message = "newmsg",
       from="abc",
      date="22/2/33"
     };
      objDB.myTableDetails.InsertOnSubmit(newrecord);
      bjDB.SubmitChanges();
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you applied the performance tips here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/12/windows-phone-local-database-tip.html ?

Comment: What DB are you using? are you storing the messages with an async call so that the UI thread is not waiting with every call to store the message? You might also want to optimize your writes to the db so that it's stored in memory until a certain threshold is reached before committing to db. Using sqlite, I can't see how you could be running into memory issues if you stored a message every few seconds to be honest, you'll need to provide more code.

Comment: @FunksMaName I'd not think, you should store messages in memory, since there is no guarantee the app is properly suspended. Otherwise I don't see a problem of storing a message async every few seconds should be a problem.

Comment: i am storing messages , when ever the message received from XMPP server .some time the message received every sec .i am not using async call